# Algorithm to map similar words to similar colors

Tags: algorithm

I was thinking it could be a cool idea to map colors to letters.

For example, if I have two words:

```
blur
blue
```

Generated color for these two words should be similar color but not identical.

Is there some algorithm that I could use to do this?

I was thinking maybe to use levenshtein() for comparing strings. This would give me how closely are two strings matched. But than I'm at alls how to generate hex numbers.

Comment: Create a 6-character base 16 hash function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any library to do this kind of thing, but the idea is interesting.

One way you could do something like this would be:

1. Map each letter to a random [unit vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector).  (A 2D vector if you only want to vary the [hue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue) of the color, a 3D vector if you also want to vary the lightness and/or saturation.)
2. Add up the vectors corresponding to the letters in the word.
3. Normalize the resulting sum vector (i.e. divide it by its length).
4. Interpret the vector as a point in the [HSV / HSL color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Note that using this method exactly as described would assign the same color to words that are [anagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram) of each other, like "tone" and "note".  If you don't want that, you can modify the method to pick a new set of random vectors for each letter position in the word.

Comment: Ps. Here's a [simple JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d2x5H/) of the concept.  Translating the code into PHP is left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks! Though your algorithm is different, color of words != word, my original idea was to make them close match based on matching characters. Maybe using levenshtein() in php.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea too.  Here's a [quick JSFiddle based on it](http://jsfiddle.net/4d8Pv/).  Basically, I'm calculating a weighted average between the color values, with the weights based on the inverse square of the Levenshtein distance.  The colors also have arbitrary intrinsic weights, both to avoid effectively assigning a double weight to synonyms like `gray` and `grey`, and so that [rare color names](http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/) may be included without having them totally swamp the basic colors.

Comment: It is awesome! now I need to understand what's happening there :)